# KendoUI Grid Filtering Issues

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using the latest version of kendoui and whenever I use the "is not equal to" or "does not contain" filter I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

I'm using a server side datasource, all the other filters seem to work without issue.

Also, how do I specify a datetimepicker for a date column?

I've looked at the documentation and tried using:

```
filterable: {
                ui: "datetimepicker"
             }
```

But it never shows the datetimepicker.

Here is the code:

```
  var dataSourceArguments = {
        pageSize:10,
        serverPaging:true,
        serverFiltering:true,
        serverSorting:true,
        transport:{
            read:{
                url:$("#grid_order").attr('data-url'),
                dataType:"json"
            }
        },
        schema:{
            total:"count",
            data:'fields'
        },
        sort:{'field':'order_date', dir:'desc'}
    };
    var ds2 = new kendo.data.DataSource(dataSourceArguments);
    $("#grid_order").kendoGrid({
        dataSource:ds2,
        groupable:true,
        scrollable:true,
        sortable:true,
        pageable:true,
        columns:[
            {
                field:'order_date',
                title:'Order Date',
                width:150,
                filterable: {
                   ui: "datetimepicker"
                }
            },
            {
                field:"reference",
                title:'Reference',
                width:120,
                encoded:false
            },
            {
                field:"client__company",
                title:'Client',
                encoded:false
            },
            {
                field:"grand_total",
                title:'Total',
                width:100
            },
            {
                field:'status',
                title:'Status',
                width:120,
                encoded:false
            },
            {
                field:'actions',
                width:200,
                title:'Actions',
                filterable:false,
                encoded:false,
                sortable:false
            }
        ],
        filterable:true
    });
```

**UPDATE:** I managed to get the datepicker working however whenever I choose the date, and click filter it filters but the date I've chosen dissapears from the field.

Comment: Would you mind to post some code showing the problem?

Comment: Since you are doing serverside filtering, are you sure that the server is processing the filtering request and sending any data back? If your browser has debugging you can check the transport and see if the request is going, returning and which data is being received.

Comment: yep it's definetly filtering and sending the data, I've been watching the xhr requests and they are being sent.. it's just that if you click the datepicker once it's filtered the date is not in the field, however it is marked on the popup calendar.. Still can't get the is not equal operator working tho..

Answer (score 2):

Add the order_date to the scheme from the data source, and the data type of the field to **date**.

See http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource